# unbind event after receiving a message that matches regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Generally, listening for an event once it's easy enough to use `once`.

```
mySocket.once('connect', () => console.log('connected!'));
```

What I am trying to do is listen for data that matches a regex. When that matching data is received, I want to unbind the event listener and resolve with the message. I can't find any easy way to do this. Preferably, I want to return a promise at the end of the function Here is one of my attempts:

```
listenOnce(regex) {
  let listener;
  let timeoutId;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Timeout exceeded')), 60000);
    listener = function (data, resolve, reject) {
      if (regex.test(data.toString('ascii'))) {
        resolve(data.toString('ascii'));
      }
    }.bind(this, resolve, reject);
    this.socket.on('data', listener);
  }).then(() => {
    this.socket.removeListener('data', listener); // this doesn't work
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is `listener` defined? It seems to be `undefined` in your function. And what are you doing with `regex`?

Comment: I think you should just promisify the `once` method and do everything else with promises.

Comment: It looks like you're headed down the right path.  But, you don't show us the `listener` function code so we can't really see what you might be doing wrong there.  What is not working in what you've tried so far?  One thing I see is that you need to `removeListener()` if you hit your timeout.  It's also not clear to me that you are binding the right `this` value in `.bind()`.

Comment: Just added that now, I must have been working on it previously, because I know I had it

Answer (score 0):

There is zero reason to use `bind` here - just let closure do its work. Your current code doesn't work because `bind` binds the first parameters, not the last, so `data` will not be the data.

```
function listenOnce(regex) {
  let listener, timeoutId;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Timeout exceeded')), 60000);
    listener = (data) => {
      const str = data.toString('ascii');
      if (regex.test(str))
        resolve(str);
    };
    this.socket.on('data', listener);
  }).finally(() => {
    this.socket.removeListener('data', listener);
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  });
}
```